# Word for updating one single "square" in a grid

Tags: word-choice

What would be an appropriate word for updating one single *square* in a grid/matrix, e.g. in a game of Tetris?
What are those *squares* called?

I was hoping for something like "Update square."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about *Updating Cell* or *Updating Unit*?

Answer (score 6):

Each individual part of a matrix is called an *element*. *Pixel* can work fine, if you feel like using an analogy with an image (*pixel* was initially short for *picture element*).

Answer (score 6):

I have always heard these terms used:

- an *element* of an array,
- an *entry* (or an *element*) of a matrix,
- a *cell* of a grid.

P.S. The following is not really a language issue, but if you're doing image processing, you should be aware that [*A Pixel is* Not *a Little Square!*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.79.9093&rep=rep1&type=pdf)